# Mac OS X Document-based App: AppleScript "open" command returning "missing value" instead of the opened document

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, applescript

My setup: 
Mac OS X 10.7.4
Xcode 4.3.2

I have a Mac OS X Document-based app which is built against the 10.6 SDK.

Previously, I had always built this app in Xcode3 on Snow Leopard.

I have recently updated the app's project to get it to build under Xcode4 on Lion (although I'm still building against the 10.6 SDK).

After building under Xcode4/Lion, I have noticed a strange change in AppleScript behavior for which I cannot find the root cause. The problem is this:

**The AppleScript open document command returns `missing value` rather than the document which was opened.**

So this code:

```
tell application "MyApp"
    set doc_ to open (get path to desktop as string) & "test.myext"
    doc_ -- prints the return value in the console
end tell
```

prints out the following value in the console when my app is built under Xcode3/Lion:

```
document 1 of application "MyApp"
```

**BUT** prints out the following value in the console when my app is built under Xcode4/Lion:

```
missing value
```

However, in both cases the Document is opened and displayed as expected. The only problem is the return value of the AppleScript `open` command.

So I dug into the code to try to figure out what is causing this change. I noticed the cause seems to be related to the behavior of this method:

```
-[NSApplication handleOpenScriptCommand:]
```

When building under Xcode3, this method blocks until an NSDocument is created in my app. This allows the AppleScript `open` command to receive my new document as its return value.

However, when building under Xcode4, this method does NOT block until the NSDocument is created. Instead, it seems to trigger some asynchronous call to

```
-[NSDocument openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:display:]
```

and return immediately. This causes the AppleScript `open` command to receive `missing value` as its return value.

So I'm trying to figure out what I've done to make this change occur.

First, I suspected I was (mis-)using the **[Asynchronous Document Opening](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDocument/canConcurrentlyReadDocumentsOfType%3a)** feature introduced in 10.6. However, I checked, and I was NOT overriding this method:

```
+[NSDocument canConcurrentlyReadDocumentsOfType:]
```

So I even tried overriding it and returning `NO`.

```
+ (BOOL)canConcurrentlyReadDocumentsOfType:(NSString *)typeName {
    return NO;
}
```

This did NOT fix my issue.

So can anyone offer advice? How might I be breaking the AppleScript `open` command to cause it to execute asynchronously (when I really want synchronous) and return `missing value` (when I really want the document that was created)?

**UPDATE**

I've discovered something very surprising!

The app in question has two incarnations: It can be built for either Independent distribution or for distribution via the Mac App Store. Each incarnation is a separate (but very similar) Target in my Xcode project. Let's call the Targets:

```
MyAppIndie
```

and

```
MyAppAppStore
```

I have discovered that this issue only happens in the Indie app. The issue does NOT happen in the AppStore build of the app.

**Also**, I have *another* Document-based OS X app which also has both an Indie and AppStore target, and it is exhibiting the same problem described here!

The AppStore version of both of my apps work correctly. But the Indie version of both apps has this problem.

I had thought there were very few differences between the two targets in both apps, but clearly something is different. I am now trying to identify all differences and find the culprit.

Hrm. Getting closer.

Comment: Have you tried providing the `openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:display:error:` call with an NSError object? Also, Considering you are building against the 10.6 SDK, this should not, by rights, be an issue, but `openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:display:error:` is deprecated in favor of `openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:display:CompletionHandler:` [in 10.7](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDocumentController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html).

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but if it's any comfort Apple can't get this right either!  When telling XCode 5 to open a file from AppleScript it too causes "missing value" to be written to stdout.

Comment: @markshep I am not sure if they "can't" or they "don't" because it is Xcode 8.1 and that script still returns the same error :/